# Creality CR10 S5; the Z dimension is wrong after switch from 0.4 to 0.2 mm nozzle

Tags: ultimaker-cura, nozzle

So I tried to print a model with a 2 mm thickness main area, and a couple 4 mm parts that stick out.

Instead the 4 mm is 3.05 mm and the 2 mm is 1.07 mm (0.042 inches measured with a caliper).

The only physical thing I changed was the nozzle from a 0.4 mm to 0.2 mm.

I changed to Ultimaker Cura 4.1 (from 4.0) and entered a 0.2 mm nozzle size in the settings. Just as before with the 0.4 mm nozzle, I used a 0.1 mm layer height.

The X and Y dimensions are good, and the screw holes line up perfectly.

I auto homed and used the bed leveling mechanism built in one many times.

Any suggestions why the height of the printed part is too small?

I don't have the model with me, but this is an example (without the holes):
[image: 3d model pic]

I am manually using the GUI of Ultimaker Cura, not the slicer engine embedded in another program or from command line.

Do I need to increase the filament temperature up from 200 to have the filament liquid enough to flow through the smaller tip?

Here is representation of it.
[image]

The old models are rigid, and the new ones bend because it is so thin.

[image]

update 6-10-19

I re-installed 4.0 to no avail.

I think the problem might be related to the filament feeder because otherwise there should be filament everywhere.  I am going to try different filament temperatures to see if that changes anything.  Trying 205. Unless the feeder motor is damaged.

Comment: Can you add a photo or diagram? It's not clear which dimensions you're talking about.

Comment: @R..     The vertical dimension or Z is not correct   Approx 6" by 1" by 2mm rectangle laying flat on the bed like a sheet of paper with holes, and bits that stick up 2mm (or there supposed to.)

Comment: Did you re-level the bed after changing nozzles? i doubt it could make this much difference though. A pic would still help.

Comment: @R..  I re-leveled 5 times.  I have included a picture of the basic design.

Comment: Your dimensions between the flat part and the step seem consistent (ie: it's very close to 2mm difference), which is what you'd expect if you were getting the right print height altogether. Was this print successfully done prior to the nozzle change? Have you tried any other prints since the nozzle change?

Comment: Have you checked the slicer output? Is it possible that your model somehow got below the XY plane and the slicer just cut off that part? I know Cura will do that if you use CuraEngine from the command line and the STL file has negative Z coordinates, or if you manually position the model below the XY plane in the GUI. Not sure if there's an easy way for it to happen accidentlaly in the GUI.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Yes, the prints were correct prior to the nozzle change, and the upgrade from 4.0 to 4.1.  The main body was 2mm, but now it 1.06mm.  I will have to check if its below the 0 point.  Something else is printing now, but won't be done for hours so I will have to check it when its done.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am using the GUI", does it really add something to the question? PLA should perfectly be extruded at 200 ºC.

Comment: @Oscar User "R.." said in the comments using the CuraEngine from the command line has issues like that.  Is 200C enough even at the smallest tips sizes?  200C was fine for 0.4mm, but maybe not for 0.2mm

Comment: But that has nothing to do with your issue, you should post pictures of the prints, else it is guess work.

Comment: @cybernard: Your picture doesn't look like there's any extrusion problem. It's possible you have some kind of Z-axis binding issue going on that's mashing all the low layers together, but I think it's more likely that the slicing went wrong. Can you check the layer count in Cura or a gcode analysis program (or just reading the gcode file) to see that the number of layers and final Z matches what you expect?

Comment: By looking into the G-code you can find out if it is sliced correctly, look up the last layer move `G1 Zxx.xx`, xx.xx should be the height of the model. If that is correct, then your Z might have a problem.